# Group of order $n!$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

If a group has order $n!$ and has trivial center then it must be isomorphic to $S_n$. Is this statement true?

Comment: There  are several groups of order $720=6!$ not isomorphic to $S_6$,  containing $A_6$ as a subgroup and contained in $Aut(A_6)$.

Comment: Trivial center is not a very strong assumption. More interesting is to ask for trivial center and abelianization $C_2$ and even then I think there are still counterexamples (Geoffrey's no longer works but I think Mark's does).

Answer (score 4):

This statement is false in general.

Consider the group $S_5 \times S_3$. This group has trivial center and order $5! \cdot 3!=5! \cdot 6=6!$, but it is not isomorphic to $S_6$, because $S_6$ has only the trivial subgroup, $A_6$, and $S_6$ itself as normal subgroups, while $S_5 \times S_3$ has two normal subgroups isomorphic to $S_5$ and $S_3$ respectively.

Comment: More generally, using the relation $$n! \cdot (n!-1)!=(n!)!$$ the group $S_{n} \times S_{n!-1}$ satisfies the given relation. This generalizes your example from $n=3$ to any $n \geq 3$.

Comment: @Arturo: You are right. Mental hiccup.Thanks.